Cannot check for instance of erased type
I have a function which accepts one parameter - Any. There is a when block where I check all possibile types I want to support and throw in case the type is unknown.
fun toAttributeValue(value: Any): AttributeValue {
    return when (value) {
        ...
        is Map<*, *> -> {
            ....
        }
        is List<*> -> {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}

In case of a Map, I need to make sure it's of type Map<String, Any>, so there cannot be a key which is not a String, and there cannot be a null value as well and the reason for that is the fact I call some method inside this block that accepts the Map<String, Any> as it suppose to.
I tried some options, but cannot find the best one, so for now I do:
val mappedValues = value.entries
    .filter { it.key is String && it.value != null }
    .associate { it.key as String to it.value!! }

require(mappedValues.size == value.size) {
    "Unsupported map type"
}

method(mappedValues)

In case of a List, I need to make sure not a single value is null, otherwise throw an exception as well. Should I do similar way I did we the Map, or is there a more handy way to do it?

Why not simply: require(value.keys.all { it is String })? Also, please be aware checking the contents doesn't solve the problem entirely. Map may be typed incorrectly, but store only the "correct" contents at the time. Then contents may change. But if you are sure map won't be modified or you create a copy, it should be fine.

@broot I need also make sure that the value is not null. My requirement is to have a Map<String, Any> as you would have in Java - Map<String, Object>, so it should have all String type keys, and value can be any type, but not null.

Ahh, right, so basically what you have inside filter, but instead of filtering, use all {} and then you can cast to Map<String, Any>. Such code differs from your original as it doesn't create a copy of the map - it could be good or not depending on your case.

Also, even your associate alone without filter and without require should do it. However, error message would be different, potentially less readable.

Instead of filtering the map/list, use methods like associateBy or map to convert the map/list to the desired type, and throw an exception in those functions if a null/non-string is found. After all, you don't want to just remove the nulls/non-strings - your aim is to throw an exception when those are found.
// suppose 'map' is of type Map<*, *>
val stringAnyMap: Map<String, Any> = map.entries.associateBy({
    (it.key as? String) ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("some key in the map is null")
}) {
    it.value ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("the value associated with key '${it.key}' is null")
}

// suppose 'list' is of type List<*>
val nonNullList: List<Any> = list.map { it ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("some element in the list is null") }

Note that this also creates a copy of the map/list. This is important because even if the map/list doesn't contain nulls/non-strings at the time when you do this check, such elements could be added to the map/list later on. Therefore, a copy is necessary, so that later changes of the original map/list will not affect the Map<String, Any> or List<Any> that you get as a result of this operation.
Of course, if you can guarantee that the Map<String, Any> and List<Any> won't escape the toAttributeValue function, and that only a single thread has access to the map/list that is passed in, you can just cast it with an unchecked cast.

I found a solution where I am able to cast it in a bit more elegant way.
val map = if (value.all { it.key is String && it.value is Any }) {
    value.cast<Map<String, Any>>()
} else {
    throw IllegalArgumentException("Illegal argument exception for unsupported map type")
}
...
private inline fun <reified T> Any.cast(): T = this as T

and in similar way with the List<*>.
